Converting edges to curves and then beveling them causing weird geometry
I made a cube and then added edge loop, deleted faces and unrequired edges and got this 
Afterword I converted it to curve so I can bevel it but I am not getting proper results on 2 ends

Is there a way to solve this or an efficient way to make a wooden fence like this?
Thanks in advance. I am fairly new to blender so this could be a dumb question.

The problem has a similar source as this one: Curve to mesh bulges at intersection, although there it is about GeoNodes. The issue is the same: too low resolution on the curves. They have endpoints and only point inbetween building a 90° angle. In this point the tangent is 45°, so the profile does not have the same height and width in vertical and horizontal direction as the endpoints. You either need more points towards the corner or set the curve to 2D, but this flattens it on Z.

Or you could have separated the edges before converting them into curves, then you would have only straight curves without any angle where this happens. Or you do not convert the mesh at all and use a Skin modifier.
